# How many ways are for creating a new thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Actually, what other ways are available apart from extending the Thread class and implementing the Runnable interface?

Comment: It is not a good approach to extend the Thread class! always use the latter one

Comment: That's basically it. There are other means to execute Runnables like ThreadPoolExecutor etc., but they all require implementing the `Runnable` interface.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is exactly one way to create a new thread in Java and that is to instantiate [`java.lang.Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) (to actually *run* that thread you also need to call `start()`).

Everything else that creates threads in Java code falls back to this one way behind the cover (e.g. a [`ThreadFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) implementation will instantiate `Thread` objects at some point,  ...).

There are two different ways to *specify which code to run* in that Thread:

- Implement the interface [`java.lang.Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and pass an instance of the class implementing it to [the `Thread` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).
- Extend `Thread` itself and override its [`run()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) method.

The first approach (implementing `Runnable`) is usually considered the more correct approach  because you don't usually create a new "kind" of Thread, but simply want to run some code (i.e. a `Runnable`) in a dedicated thread.

Comment: I am surprised that they haven't deprecated Thread#run() by now.  They really ought to do.  The idea that a Thread _is_ a Runnable is very old-fashioned, and relatively limiting compared to the idea that a Thread _has_ a runnable.  Same goes for other classes to:  "has a" is often ore powerful than "is a".

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - what about callable ? does it also falls back to instantiating the Thread class ?

Comment: @SantanuSahoo: `Callable` is pretty similar to `Runnable` in that it in itself doesn't do anything related to threads, but it can be used in various ways to pass code to execute in some way, including in another thread. So if you pass a `Callable` to your `ExecutorService` then it may very well end up running on a new thread, but the actual instantion of the thread will still be done via `new Thread` somewhere behind the scenes.

Answer (score 26):

Threads can be created mainly in 3 different ways

1. **Extend** the java.lang.**Thread** class'

```
class SampleThread extends Thread {

    //method where the thread execution will start 
    public void run(){
        //logic to execute in a thread    
    }

    //let’s see how to start the threads
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Thread t1 = new SampleThread();
       Thread t2 = new SampleThread();
       t1.start();  //start the first thread. This calls the run() method.
       t2.start(); //this starts the 2nd thread. This calls the run() method.  
    }
}
```

2. **Implement** the java.lang.**Runnable** interface

```
class A implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // implement run method here 
    }

    public static void main() {
        final A obj = new A();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new A());

        t1.start();
    }


}
```

3. **Implement** the java.util.concurrent.**Callable** interface

```
class Counter implements Callable {

    private static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 2;

    // method where the thread execution takes place
    public String call() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName() + " executing ...";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException {
        // create a pool of 2 threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);

        Future future1 = executor.submit(new Counter());
        Future future2 = executor.submit(new Counter());

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " executing ...");

        //asynchronously get from the worker threads
        System.out.println(future1.get());
        System.out.println(future2.get());

    }
}
```

Favor Callable interface with the Executor framework for thread pooling.

The Runnable or Callable interface is preferred over extending the Thread class

Comment: Think you need to Override in the event of extending, Thread, not in the event you are implementing an Interface, Runnable.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can create a [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) which is an interface which is similar to Runnable except that it defines a method **call** that can return a value. To instantiante a Callable, you can pass it to an executor. You can find a full explanation of multithreading and callable examples [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures)

Comment: To _instantiate_ a Callable, you use the Java "new" operator, same way you instantiate any other object.  To _use_ a callable, you either call its "Call()" method or, you hand it off to some other object (e.g., an ExecutorService) that will call it for you at some appropriate, future time in some appropriate context, and maybe in some appropriate thread.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way of starting threads in Java 6 is using Executors:

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Runnable r = <your runnable here>;
    es.execute(r);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that's the preferred way of executing code concurrently. If you *really* want to start a dedicated `Thread`, then that's not the way.

Comment: @Joachim I think is OK to use thread here. Notice the lowercase t in thread. And these executors actually create and manage Threads.

Comment: @Gray it has both methods: `execute(Runnable)` and another `submit(Callable<T>)`.

Comment: @MisterSmith, If you want to start a thread, call Thread#start().  If you want to run a _task_, use an executor service.  An ExecutorService may start a thread to run your task, or it may re-use an existing thread, or it may simply execute the task in the calling thread.  The ExecutorService interface only says that the task must eventually be performed, and that you must get back a Future that lets you wait for the result.  There are other uses for threads besides executing tasks.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually total 4 ways to create thread in java :

1. By extending `java.lang.Thread` class
2. By implementing `java.lang.Runnable` interface
3. By using anonymous inner class
4. By implementing `Callable` interface.

Comment: Implementing threads into separate other class or as an anonymous class is just a way of using it. As above described, there are only 3 ways to implement threads.

Answer (score 1):

There are only Two ways for creating a Thread already you have mentioned but a third way is there to invoke the Thread.

In java1.5 there is another way to invoke a thread. That is by “ExecutorService”. All these classes are from the “java.util.concurrent” package. There are various ways to create a “ExecutorService” using “Executors” factory class. The following is one of the way to create “ExecutorService”..

**ExecutorService es= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();**

**RunnableImpl r = new RunnableImpl();**

**Future fu=es.submit(r);**

Using “ExecutorService” methods we can submit eighter Runnable or Callable to the service for execution.

How ever this cannot be said as the new way to create a Thread. It is because ExecutorService internally uses “ThreadFactory” class to create a new thread which internally uses eighter first or second method. So we have to say that there are only two ways to create threads but there is a new way in java1.5 to invoke a thread but not to create a Thread.

Comment: Agree, but callable is still another way to create a thread. With Callable you can return value from the thread using future once its done so its certainly different than runnable and hence

Answer (score 0):

for creating a thread there is only one way in java

ie. Thread class start()  method but there are different ways to run the thread
by using different ways

like 1.Thread
     2.Runnable
     3.RunnableFeature
     4.Callable
     5.ERxecutorService...etc