# Thread Creation Difference

Tags: java, multithreading

I have studied that we can create threads in two ways in java :

1. By extending Thread Class
2. By implementing `Runnable` interface under which we have to implement `run()`

Now my question is what is the difference b/w the two?

Is any 1 faster or efficient than other? something related to binding here or linking?

Comment: Check out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280881/how-many-ways-are-for-creating-a-new-thread-in-java.

Comment: -1 because a google search for "java thread runnable difference" would have given you all the answers you need

Answer (score 1):

A `Thread` is a resource for performing work.

A `Runnable` is a unit of work.

Are you creating a new type of resource, or defining work?  It's almost always the later.

In the simplest case there isn't really any functional performance difference.  However, creating `Runnable`s allows you to utilize Thread pools without changing your code much, which is a huge boost over using `new Thread()` in many cases.