# Quick Java Anonymous function/class question

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class

I know how anonymous functions work in JS and all but a bit confused on parts of it in Java.

So below I have an anonymous class (I'm just using the Thread class as an example to what I've seen), where I override the *run()* function and then call *.start()* on that class.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from the anonymous class thread");
    }
}.start();
```

So this works, but IntelliJ wants to me re-write it as this:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello from the anonymous class thread")).start();
```

I get most of this syntax, but just a bit confused as to how the *run()* function is being overridden. From my understanding, there is no parameter being passed into the Thread class (so nothing being passed into the constructor I'm assuming). Now where I'm confused is here. It doesn't state anywhere that it is *overriding* the *run()* function. Is this a special case for the *Thread* class or is there something I am missing?

Hope that I explained this clearly and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax that IntelliJ proposes to you is not more of an "oblique" translation of your original code, and does not actually override `Thread.run` like your original code does.

Your original code creates an anonymous subclass of `Thread` with `run` overridden, whereas the proposed syntax by IntelliJ calls [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-) of `Thread` that accepts a `Runnable`. The lambda expression represents the `Runnable`. If we "expand" the lambda expression into an anonymous class, we will be actually doing this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from the anonymous class thread");
    }
}).start();
```

So we are creating an anonymous implementation of `Runnable`, and implementing `Runnable.run` instead.

> It doesn't state anywhere that it is overriding the `run()` function.

True, but `run` is the only abstract method in the `Runnable` interface, so Java is able to figure out that you are overriding that method.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great explanation. Is there a difference to actually overriding the _run()_ function like I was before versus having a _new Runnable()_ instance then overriding the _run()_ function?

Comment: @thatdevopNB The threads should do the same thing. But passing in a `Runnable` makes more sense to me. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7280925/5133585)

Answer (score 4):

The `run()` function is being overridden implicitly because it's the only method of the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, which makes it a *functional interface*. A functional interface has exactly one abstract method. This special property of an interface allows you to implement it *implicitly* using a lambda expression. The compiler knows you're providing an implementation of the `Runnable.run()` method, because it's the only method inside the interface.

If you take a look at the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, you'll see that it is decorated with the [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation. This annotation ensures that the decorated interface can never have more than one abstract method (or else the compiler will fail). Note that this annotation is not required in order for the implicit lambda feature to work.